# Moment.js handles german Dezember and Januar different

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

i wonder why moment.js handels some Month diffrent. For example in german:
Mai, März, Oktober, Dezember dont work to convert toDate(). Every other month works. I think because these four Month dont start with the first 3 letters same as english. German Jan/uar is the same as english Jan/uary. So this works.

I have set my lang of moment globally to German so i dont know why this happens.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49oLnme1/) for testing. And the Code:

```
var now = moment('7. Dezember 2016').toDate();
alert(now);

var now = moment('9. Januar 2016').toDate();
alert(now);
```

Comment: In the fiddle, both fail. Also, in the fiddle you only link to a moment.js file that does not contain any translations. Please provide a real [mcve]. Please also show how you set the momentjs language

Comment: Also, you are using an outdated version of moment.js (2.2.1) in the fiddle. Why?

Comment: The fiddle was just a fork from a diffrent fiddle. I did not check the version there. In my React app i am using the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version which works as expected: (Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/akuxjoge/)

```
moment.locale('de');

let dt = moment("7. Dezember 2016", "LL").toDate();
alert(dt);

dt = moment("9. Januar 2016", "LL").toDate();
alert(dt);
```

I use the latest version of moment.js which already comes with the locales.

```
https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js
```

Problem with your code:

You cannot just pass any date format to the `moment()` function. momentjs will only recognize some specific formats. If it does not recognize the format, it will pass the task of parsing the string as a date/time to the browser. So, the specific behavior you see is your browser trying to parse the string.

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of new Date(string) if a known format is not found.
>   (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

To solve the problem, specify a [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) (In this case "`LL`") as the second parameter to specify what format the string uses.

Comment: Thanks that works just finde now. And a very god explanation.